# Why is this defined value not recognized as a package or object reference?

Tags: perl, class, testing

I have the code below:

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content((charset => 'UTF-8'));
my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(\$content) || $logger->error("When retrieving $URL: ", XML::Feed->errstr);
if (defined $feed) {
   for my $entry ($feed->entries) {
      #DO SOMETHING
   }
}
```

For some site, XML::FEED saying that it can't detect the feed type. This is something I have to look at but this is not my question at the moment.
This sample code is inside a while loop has I'm retrieving different RSS and I would like to have the script running even when some URLs failed.

The defined function seems to not work as I get the error message:

> Can't call method "entries" without a package or object reference

Can someone tell me what is the right way to handle the test?

Comment: Tag appropriately for the language you're using.

Comment: Did you do a check on **$content** before parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to check the value of $feed.

The error message you describe is obvious: $feed is not a package / object reference, but it can be a simple hash for instance. So it's defined.

Add my favourite debugging line right in front of if(defined):

```
warn Data::Dumper->new([ $feed ],[ '*feed' ])->Sortkeys(1)->Dump();use Data::Dumper;
```

and you'll see the value in a nice way.
Without testing I'd say that $feed contains the result of your logger, which might be 1 or 0 or something like that, because you set the value of $feed to XML::Feed->parse, and if this is not successful (undefined) it's the result of $logger->error.

You'd better write it like:

```
my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(\$content);

if (defined $feed) {
    for my $entry ($feed->entries) {
        #DO SOMETHING
    }
}
else {
    $logger->error("When retrieving $URL: ", XML::Feed->errstr);
}
```

because parse is said to return an object, and I guess it returns undef on error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code you proposed work like a charm. Actually, I don't understand why but it looks like retrieving XML::Feed->errstr set $feed to a integer. So testing $feed with define() after retrieving XML::Feed->errstr doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

The error message means what it says:  `$feed` is neither a package nor an object reference.  It passes the `defined` test because there are many defined values which are neither packages nor object references.

In this particular case, you're seeing this error because you are misuing `||`:

```
my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(\$content) || $logger->error("When retrieving $URL: ", XML::Feed->errstr);
```

If the `parse` call should fail and return `undef`, this evaluates to

```
my $feed = ( undef || $logger->error("When retrieving $URL: ", XML::Feed->errstr) );
```

which evaluates to

```
my $feed = $logger->error("When retrieving $URL: ", XML::Feed->errstr);
```

.  The return value of `$logger->error` is unknown to me, but presumably it is neither a package nor an object reference.  And if it were one, it probably would be the wrong one to put in a variable named `$feed`.

[The documentation for `XML::Feed`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Feed/lib/XML/Feed.pm) mentions parsing with a construct like

```
my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(URI->new('http://example.com/atom.xml'))
        or die XML::Feed->errstr;
```

**This is not the same thing.**  Their respective precedence rules make `||` and `or` suitable for different applications; specifically, you should only use `||` when you want the value on the right-hand side for something.  Do not use it only for the short-circuit side effect.

You can solve this by replacing the `||` with `or` to get the right evaluation order.  While you are there, you probably should also eliminate the redundant `defined` test.